# Opencv storing Yuyv (YCrCb) in cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, colors, mat

I'm the data I get out of my webcam is yuv422.  I'd like to store this yuv422 into a cv::Mat without converting it to RGB...  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have direct access to the frame you can warp your data in Mat using the *data member. `cv::Mat` is generic type, it's not strictly RGB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the chroma subsampling, it's probably going to be simpler if you unpack the `YUYV` data into a `YUV` matrix (3 channels of 8-bit data), then perform your filtering with `cv::inRange` etc. You just need to interpolate the U and V samples for each Y.

Another alternative would be to treat the matrix as 4 channels of 8-bit data, and then in your filter results, combine the results from the two `Y` sample channels.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just create a 3 channel matrix. Please take a look at the [basic Mat tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html)

Comment: Essenitially, what I would like to do is use `cv::inRange` on the yuv422 data; however, since the data is 422, I'm not really sure how I can do this.  Furthermore, I don't think I want 3 channel but rather two channel because the data is stored as Y0U Y1V.

Comment: Then create a two channel mat. The documentation is quite good on how to use Mat objects.

Comment: Yes I did...  but then I can't really usr the `cv::inRange` function because every odd nybble represents either `U` or `V` and every even nybble represents `Y`.  Do you know if there is a way to store the image so that then I can use the opencv functions (such as `cv::inRange`)?  I'm wondering if there is some way to tell opencv that the data is yuv422 because if it doesn't know that, all the methods won't work.